# Windows Phone 8 MonoGame Initialize not being called

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, xna, monogame

I'm trying to create a WP8 game using MonoGame 3.2 in VS2013. I've made XNA games for WP7 in the past and am perplexed as to why this is happening.

I've got the unmodified WindowsPhone8 monogame template pulled up and am able to compile and deploy but the emulator just shows black (not cornflower blue). I've stepped thru the code and see that the Game1 class constructor is being executed. At this point I would expect Initialize, LoadContent, Update, Draw to be executed... but nothing. Just the constructor.

Am I missing a step? Not sure where to start looking if its a config problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Seems I'm not alone in this but... no answers :(

https://monogame.codeplex.com/workitem/7607?FocusElement=CommentTextBox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok... So to fix this you need to install the latest SharpDX (2.5 at the time of writing). Then add a reference to the SharpDX.dll for the correct platform(x86/arm) in your project. And boom! it works.

Comment: Seems like MonoGame should at least throw an exception. I'd class this behavior as a bug.

Comment: I'm also having this problem, but the latest SharpDX.dll didn't fix it for me. There was already a SharpDX.dll in my bin folder but I replaced it with the new one and manually added a reference to it in my project (there wasn't a reference before). Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In the GamePage.xaml, replace the Grid with DrawingSurfaceBackgroundGrid. it should work.

```
  <DrawingSurfaceBackgroundGrid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">

        <MediaElement></MediaElement>

  </DrawingSurfaceBackgroundGrid>
```